# How would I display the 5th onwards iteration of a razor template loop

Tags: razor

I'm new to razor and I have a loop like so:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.list)
 {

 }
```

I need to display the 5th model onwards in the list (so the 5th iteration onwards of the loop)

How best should I do this?  I'd imagine this should be really simple.

Any tips/suggestions would be grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `list` is index-able.

```
  @for (int i = 5; i < Model.list.Count; i++)
  {
       var item = Model.list[i];            
  }
```

If not then

```
  @{
  var array = Model.list.ToArray();
  }
  @for (int i = 5; i < array.Length; i++)
  {
       var item = array[i];  
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, just tried it and `list` isn't index-able :( .... any other ideas?